# python debugger: initialising variables not interactively

Tags: python, batch-processing, pdb

I am running a code with pdb. The run is breaking at line 3, I insert `setvars` and some variables are changed.

```
python -m pdb -c "b 3" -c c -c "alias setvars aaa=1;bbb=1" somecode.py 3
```

This does what I want interactively, but I would like to run this as a batch job, because I would like to run it on a cluster. So, I would like to set the variables `aaa` and `bbb` at breakpoint 3 and then continue without any user interaction.

Is it possible? or maybe I am using the wrong tool to achieve this?

NOTE: this is a follow-up question of [python debugger initialising with file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50065682/python-debugger-initialising-with-file)

Comment: What about modifying your "somecode.py" script so that you can pass the desired values as arguments ?

Comment: of course. but I am also trying to explore the potentialities of pdb, because I have never found a tutorial beyond the simplest commands

Comment: Well that's another question then.. but the answer to your "maybe I am using the wrong tool" question is obviously "yes"  - pdb is a step debugger, not a tool to pass arguments to a script.

Comment: I think it is possible that one wants to debug a code in batch mode. sometimes anomalous behaviour only occurs in some specific context. let's say you have a code that only doesn't work on some specific data that you only can load in not-interactive mode. Then you want to force some variable to be something else during execution. I think this is a legitimate use of a debugger, interfering with behaviour at run-time, isn't it?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, this is not a "legitimate use" of a step debugger but a complete WTF. If you want to handle exceptional situations, use exceptions and exception handlers. If you want per-environment variables, use per-environment settings. A step debugger is an __interactive__ developer tool, period.

Comment: ok, I understand your point of view. Let me just add that when I say that I use a debugger most of the people ask why don't you just use `print()`, and it is true that for debugging a code you don't need a debugger but you can just modify the code. I don't want to argue anything, just clarifying why I asked the question in first place

Comment: I do use pdb - logging (proper logging using the `logging` lib) and unittests do save a lot of time and effort but are not up to par with a proper step debugger for some problems - so my point is not that "you should not use pdb", just that it's not the right tool for what you want to do here, which is not debugging in any way not form.